# OperationalError: no such table: entries

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am learning flask framework and was following the flask [tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/). I have followed every step of this tutorial line-by-line. In the end I am getting the error "**sqlite3.OperationalError  OperationalError: no such table: entries"**. I am on linux machine and have never used sqlite before. I dont know how to tackle this problem. And the code of **flaskr.py** is here below

```
# all the imports
import os
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, render_template, flash



# create our little application :)
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
# Load default config and override config from an environment variable
app.config.update(dict(
DATABASE=os.path.join(app.root_path, 'flaskr.db'),
DEBUG=True,
SECRET_KEY='development key',
USERNAME='admin',
PASSWORD='default'
))
app.config.from_envvar('FLASKR_SETTINGS', silent=True)


def connect_db():
# """Connects to the specific database."""
    rv = sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
    rv.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return rv

def init_db():
    with app.app_context():
        db = get_db()
    with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
        db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
        db.commit()


def get_db():
#"""Opens a new database connection if there is none yet for the current application context."""
    if not hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
        g.sqlite_db = connect_db()
        return g.sqlite_db


@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_db(error):
#"""Closes the database again at the end of the request."""
    if hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
        g.sqlite_db.close()



@app.route('/')
def show_entries():
    db = get_db()
    cur = db.execute('select title, text from entries order by id desc')
    entries = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries)



@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add_entry():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        abort(401)
        db = get_db()
        db.execute('insert into entries (title, text) values (?, ?)',
        [request.form['title'], request.form['text']])
        db.commit()
        flash('New entry was successfully posted')
    return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))



@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != app.config['USERNAME']:
            error = 'Invalid username'
        elif request.form['password'] != app.config['PASSWORD']:
            error = 'Invalid password'
        else:
            session['logged_in'] = True
            flash('You were logged in')
        return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    flash('You were logged out')
    return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Can you show us your code? Are you sure you followed [step 4](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/dbinit/) and that the database file is correctly loaded?

Comment: I note that the bottom of that page (step 4) has a specific section about troubleshooting: *If you get an exception later that a table cannot be found*

Comment: That looks correct. So you have a `flaskr.db` file in your project root? Did you call the `init_db()` function from an interactive prompt, as detailed in step 4?

Comment: Just make sure ~entries~ table is created in sql. Open sql console and type `show tables;`. This will show the list of tables created in SQL

Comment: I now looked at the flaskr.db file. It is empty. Should I just type init_db() at its first line?

Comment: I do know how to look at the tables in mysql through console but dont know about sqlite

Comment: There is a `sqlite3` command line utility, or you could use one of the [GUIs available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835069/which-sqlite-administration-console-do-you-recommend). You need to follow step 4 properly. Open a Python interactive prompt, `from flaskr import init_db`, then `init_db()`.

Comment: I did this as you said and now it is saying                      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "flaskr.py", line 33, in init_db
    db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed database.

Comment: Do you know how to open closed database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. I need to create the tables first before the execution of code. So I just opened the python shell and typed the following commands. This function created the required tables in my database.

```
 from flaskr import init_db
 init_db()
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I'm following the same tutorial, but building everything in Pycharm.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply doing

```
from flaskr import init_db
init_db()
```

will throw a RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

What you can do is, in your flaskr.py add

```
with app.app_context():
      init_db()
```

and then run flaskr.py. Now when you execute

```
export FLASK_APP=flaskr.py
export FLASK_DEBUG=1
flask run
```

everything would run smoothly!

Comment: This worked for me, the solution above did not.  I put the code you suggested right above if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()